# LSTM, multi-variate, multi-feature in pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, lstm

I'm having trouble understanding the format of data for an LSTM in pytorch.    Lets say i have a CSV file with 4 features, laid out in timestamps one after the other ( a classic time series)

```
time1 feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
time2 feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
time3 feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
time4 feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4,  label
```

However, this entire set of 4 sequences only has a single label.  The thing we're trying to classify started at time1, but we don't know how to label it until time 4.
My question is, can a typical pytorch LSTM support this? All of the tutorials i've read, watched, walked through, involve looking at a time sequence of a single feature, or a word model, which is still a dataset with a single dimension.

If it can support it, does the data need to be flattened in some way?

Pytorch's LSTM reference states:

input: tensor of shape (L,N,Hin)(L, N, H_{in})(L,N,Hin​) when batch_first=False or (N,L,Hin)(N, L, H_{in})(N,L,Hin​) when batch_first=True containing the features of the input sequence. The input can also be a packed variable length sequence.

Does this mean that it cannot support any input that contains multiple sequences?  Or is there another name for this?

I'm really lost here, and could use any advice, pointers, help, so on.   Maybe some disambiguation too.

I've posted a couple times here but gotten no responses at all. If this post is misplaced, could someone kindly direct me towards the correct place to post it?

Edit: Following Daniel's advice, do i understand correctly that the four features should be put together like this:

```
[(feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4), label]  when given to the LSTM?
```

If that's correct, is the input size (16) in this case?

Finally, I was under the impression that the output of the LSTM Would be the predicted label.  Do I have that wrong?

Comment: What is the dimensionality of the features? Are they scalars?

Comment: Each feature is a float, of different ranges, but they are definitely scalars.

Comment: Hi, better to post questions regarding a given answers as a comment to the answer. Otherwise it's hard to answer it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you show, the LSTM layer's input size is (batch_size, Sequence_length, feature_size). This means that the feature is assumed to be a 1D vector.

So to use it in your case you need to stack your four features into one vector (if they are more then 1D themselves then flatten them first) and use that vector as the layer's input.

Regarding the label. It is defiantly supported to have a label only after a few iterations. The LSTM will output a sequence with the same length as the input sequence, but when training the LSTM you can choose to use any part of that sequence in the loss function. In your case you will want to use the last element only.

Comment: Please see my edit (being new here i'm unsure if this is the proper way to respond to your question), to confirm that I understand your response. And thanks.

Comment: Understood, thank you. Is this the correct format then, in my example? [(feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4), label] Also regarding the other comment, I thought the output of the LSTM Would be the predicted label, is that incorrect? @DanielTomer

Comment: the answer to the edit is no. First of all the label is not given as input to the layer. Second It should be np.array([[[feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4], [feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4], [feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4], [feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4]]]). Giving a (1x4x4) array.

Comment: I must be very confused -- I thought part of the training process was to give labeled sequences, after which when presented with a test set of sequences of the same dimensions, we get a predicted label for that set of sequences.  Have I got this process all wrong?  If that statement is false, then how does one label the data?

Comment: The output of the LSTM depends on the value you give to "hidden_size" variable. and in your case it will be a tensor of size (1x4xhidden_size). After that you can decide to do whatever you want with it. if you only have a label for the last part of the sequence you will probably want to only use output[:, -1, :]

Comment: So is the label included as part of the input tensor then?  (not separate)  Doesn't that make an oddly shaped tensor?

Comment: The label is part of the training procedure but not given as input to the model itself. Usually what happens is you have a (input, label) pair. The input is given to the model which outputs some tensor (usually called y_pred). Then this output tensor is given to a loss function together with the label to produce a loss score

Comment: Oh I see.  Rather than getting off track, since you've answered my original question, let me post a separate question about this. Thank you so much, you've been very helpful.